# MongoDB export float _id

Tags: php, mongodb

I've just started using mongoDB and have some questions.
First one: 
I have imported csv file to MongoDB 
 When I try to find data in mongo cli, I get _id's like this:

```
db.test.find({}, {_id: 1}).limit(5);
{ "_id" : NumberLong("724756511264022954") }
{ "_id" : NumberLong("7925523805856237974") }
{ "_id" : NumberLong("3278364823767039230") }
{ "_id" : 12477933649175871000 }
{ "_id" : 9648786610610065000 }
```

But, PHP, [MongoDB Driver](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php)

```
$conn = new \Mongo('127.0.0.1');
$db = $conn->test_db;
$collection = $db->test;
$cursor = @$collection->find([])->timeout(-1)->limit(5);
foreach ( $cursor as $document ) {
    echo $document['_id'] . "\n";
}
```

returns this:

724756511264022954
 7925523805856237974
 3278364823767039230
 1.2477933649176**E+19**
 9.6487866106101**E+18**

```
echo sprintf("%u", ($document['_id'])) . "\n";
```

returns wrong result too..

724756511264022954
7925523805856237974
3278364823767039230
12477933649175871**488**
9648786610610065**408**

How can I return full integer result?
Maybe, there is any way to convert all ids to **ObjectId**?

**BYW:** mongoexport returns results with E+19

Comment: It's correct. Some of your values are `NumberLong` but the others that do not show that are actually `Double` as a BSON type, which is of course technically a floating point value. If you expect different then you need to recast the other values as `NumberLong` ( BSON 64-bit integer ). But of course you cannot just do that with an `_id`, so you would need to remove the documents and rewrite them instead. Works as designed.